# Как отключить увеличение поле id в ms sql 2012 при зеркалировании?

Tags: sql, sql-server, администрирование

Добрый день! Имеется схема из 3 серверов ms sql 2012 для зеркалирования бд (основной-следящий-зеркальный). Накидал тестовую базу с несколькими таблицами, добавил немного данных. Настроил всю эту связку все подключилось и работает.
 Провожу тесты:
Выключаю основную машину, режим автоматически меняется и резервный сервак позволяет работать с бд. И тут начинается проблема. При добавлении новых записей в бд на резервном серваке id увеличивается на 1000. При восстановлении связи и записи в бд на основном сервере id снова увеличивается на 1000. Тестировал на 2008 sql сервере, там id не увеличивался. Подскажите где это отключить?
 Спасибо

Comment: 1000 небольшая потеря. А логика работы БД не должна зависеть от того как назначаются id. Вообще в документации https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms186775.aspx написано, что если пропуске недопустимы то следует использовать другие механизмы назначения id

Comment: Просто в проекте уже есть бд с данными за 5 лет. Структура определена и менять ее никто не будет. Поэтому надо использовать что есть. Я думаю можно найти где изменяется поведение назначения id при зеркалировании. Вот только где?

Comment: http://www.dfarber.com/computer-consulting-blog/2014/2/13/how-to-solve-identity-problem-in-sql-2012.aspx

Comment: Дело не в зеркалировании. Дело в кэшированиии значений identity. Это известная особенность (см. Connect [раз](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity), [два](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/743300/identity-column-jumps-by-seed-value), а также en-SO [раз](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14146148), [два](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14162648), [три](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17587094)). Есть workaround-ы (ценой понижения производительности), так что смотрите, стоит ли заморачиваться.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Краткий ответ: подобное поведение можно отключить трейс-флагом 272.

Полный ответ: В 2012 SQL Server'е был реализован новый механизм кэширования значений IDENTITY - они выделяются сразу блоком и хранятся в памяти до присвоения конкретным строкам. Такой механизм повысил производительность выделения IDENTITY, но привел к указанной вами особенности поведения, поскольку при выключении сервера закэшированные значения IDENTITY теряются, и при следующем включении сервер кэширует следующий блок значений. Данное поведение можно отключить флагом 272, при этом новый механизм кэширования отключится и поведение будет тем же, что в версии 2008R2 (по заверениям разработчиков).

Ссылки по теме (обращение на Microsoft Connect) уже привел выше @i-one в комментарии к вопросу:

- [Failover or Restart Results in Reseed of
  Identity](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/739013/failover-or-restart-results-in-reseed-of-identity)
- [Identity Column Jumps by Seed
  Value](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/743300/identity-column-jumps-by-seed-value)